# Register multiple admin classes for django-import-export

Tags: python, django, admin, django-import-export

I would like to have different export formats for a model, so one of them includes additional metadata not present in the others.

I can create a ModelResource subclass for both export formats, but I would like to allow the user select them from the admin interface.

It is something like this:

```
class IngredientColourRelation(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.CharField()
    colour_label = models.CharField()
    metadata = models.CharField()

class IngredientColourLabelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """Ingredient Resource class for importing and exporting."""

    ingredient = resources.Field()
    colour_label = resources.Field()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class"""
        model = IngredientColourRelation

        fields = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label',)
        export_order = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label',)
```

The other resource is like:

```
class MetadataIngredientColourLabelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """Ingredient Resource class for importing and exporting."""

    ingredient = resources.Field()
    colour_label = resources.Field()
    metadata = resources.Field()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class"""
        model = IngredientColourRelation

        fields = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label', 'metadata',)
        export_order = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label', 'metadata',)
```

I thought I may register both Resources through two Admin classes, like:

```
class IngredientColourLabelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    """Ingredient import-export Admin interface"""
    resource_class = IngredientColourLabelResource

class MetadataIngredientColourLabelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    """Ingredient import-export Admin interface"""
    resource_class = MetadataIngredientColourLabelResource

admin.site.register(IngredientColourRelation, IngredientColourLabelAdmin)
admin.site.register(IngredientColourRelation, MetadataIngredientColourLabelAdmin)
```

But only the lastest one is used when I click on the export button from the change-list view.

Any suggestion on how to proceed to allow users to choose different Resource formats?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a proxy model, like this:

```
class IngredientColourRelationWithMetadataExport(IngredientColourRelation):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "IngredientColourRelation (Exports Metadata)"
```

This model will share the same database table and return the same data as the original model, but you can register it separately in the Admin. You can also add additional methods and properties (but not fields), if that would be useful.

Change the model reference in `MetadataIngredientColourLabelResource` to use the proxy model:

```
class MetadataIngredientColourLabelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """Ingredient Resource class for importing and exporting."""

    ingredient = resources.Field()
    colour_label = resources.Field()
    metadata = resources.Field()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class"""
        model = IngredientColourRelationWithMetadataExport

        fields = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label', 'metadata',)
        export_order = ('id', 'ingredient', 'colour_label', 'metadata',)
```

Then you can register the two models separately in the Admin:

```
admin.site.register(IngredientColourRelation, IngredientColourLabelAdmin)
admin.site.register(IngredientColourRelationWithMetadataExport, 
    MetadataIngredientColourLabelAdmin)
```